# SSH-Keygen user privileges- issue

Tags: server, 18.04, permissions, ssh, sudo

I am trying to SSH from one ubuntu18.04 machine to another. For that created a separate user in both machines and added that user in sudo group and edited sshd_config file for PubKeyAuthentication=yes and restarted ssh service.

Then under the createduser in 1st machine, generated ssh-keygen,
copied that id_rsa.pub key to 2nd machine under created user,
ssh-copy-id -i id_rsa.pub newuser2@[ip-of-2ndmachine]

Now im able to ssh to the 2nd machine without password,
but when i execute apt update, its showing permission denied,
how to execute the same without password now?

Note: If I give sudo apt update, its asking password, after passing password the cmd is executing.

Can someone help me to execute all cmds in 2nd machine without providing password with newuser(not root).

Answer (score 0):

Apt commands must be executed with super user privileges, normally through the use of sudo. This usually requires you entering your passphrase. You could set up passwordless sudo on the 2nd machine for `apt` commands, or more safely for specific `apt` commands to achieve your goal.

To set up passwordless sudo, you will need to have sudo access already as the `visudo` commad, used to edit the sudoers file, is another command requiring root level privileges.

To edit the sudoers file with your default text editor:

```
sudo visudo
```

Add the following line to allow passwordless access to all `apt` commands (replacing user with your actual username):

```
user ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt
```

It's safer to restrict sudo access as much as possible so if you know the precise commands you're likely to run, enter those instead:

```
user ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt update
user ALL= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/apt upgrade
```

Close the file and save changes to enable the new access level, you will still need to use `sudo` for your commands but will not need to enter the passphrase.

Be aware that granting passwordless `sudo` access too liberally can break the security of your system. When done incorrectly it means that anyone that can log in as your user can elevate their privileges to root level and do anything on your system.

Comment: Passwordless sudo means, you are mentioning this-- %sudo  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL.

Comment: I've added information on how to do that. The % symbol means that you're granting sudo access to a group. The line you've posted would grant passwordless sudo to any command for any user in the sudo group. That's probably a bit too open, being as restrictive as practical is a good thing.

Comment: Yeah sure, I will edit the file accordinly... Actually I was executing an ansible-playbook with apt command which results this issue. Have attached the image for your reference, kindly let me know if have any idea.

Comment: Let me know if have any idea on this.
---
- hosts: webservers
  become: yes
  become_user: ansnode
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
  - name: "installing webserver"
    apt:
       name: apache2
       update_cache: yes
       state: present


Executing play: ansible-playbook apachews.yml

PLAY [webservers] 
***********************
fatal: [172.xx.xx.xx]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation"}

PLAY RECAP
172.xx.xx.xx              : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Comment: I don't really have any experience with ansible I'm afraid. You should probably ask a new question to get information on that. It's also worth looking at the [tour] page to find out how this site works in regards to asking questions and accepting answers.